# WindowsSdkDir per project?

Tags: visual-c++, build, windows-ce, winapi, poco-libraries

I have a Visual C++ library which I want to compile for a certain platform (I try to compile POCO for a Win CE ARM platform, but that might not be relevant to this question). I got a vendor-specific Windows CE SDK (including all common Windows include files e.g. winbase.h) which is set as target platform within the Visual Studio project files. However, when I compile the program, I can see from the error log that the default Windows 6.0A SDK is used, resulting in a bunch of compilation errors.

I guess the WindowsSdkDir ist not set accordingly - I thought this would be automatically overriden when setting the target platform within Visual Studio.

So my question is: can I modify the WindowsSdkDir for a single project explicitly?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Was the library project originally built to target the SDK you want?  If not, create a new project file and "Add Existing" all of the source files.  Studio is really, really bad when trying to add a new SDK/Platform to an existing project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which CE version, which VS version and on which Windows version? I know that I had problems installing CE5 and/or CE6 SDKs and getting them recognized by Visual Studio 2005 running on Windows 7 (64 bit). I don't remember the exact symptoms and fix, but you can test that by simply creating a smart device project for the target SDK.

If that is not the issue, there is also the pitfall with the target in both the project file (.vcproj) and the solution (.sln). You can change both independently from each other, up to the point where you compile the x64 debug version of a project in the win32 release version of the solution. Verify that these setting match.

Then, if you adjusted the .vcproj file to use your target platform (for which I personally would use a text editor), things should work. If you need to adjust the build or some paths, you can sometimes get by with e.g $(Platform) in the compiler/linker settings.

Lastly, if all that doesn't work, there are property sheets, which can adjust certain settings. You then create a property sheet once and then load it into the project that you want to compile. I'm not sure if you can change the target platform or the SDK paths with that approach though, and I'd rather try to find out why the SDK doesn't work and how to fix it instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now everything works fine, though I could not fix the issue by building from command line. But when I build within Visual Studio, it works.